# Why does getTag return always 0 for my imageview clicklistener?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-view, android-inflate

So far I have implemented a button that on every click inflates a new imageView
now I'm trying to assign a tag to each imageView but in my case is returning always 0.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

public void addImage(View view){

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {


        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 84));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.text);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);

        imageView.setTag(i);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: String.valueOf((int)v.getTag())

Comment: I know the problem stays at the lines:for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)  and  imageView.setTag(i); but can't figure it out how to do it

Comment: ????? Did you try my code? I did not talk about setTag() as that is ok. I talked about getTag() as that is your problem.

Comment: Yes I did,unfortunately same result 0. It reads that as same imageview because I'm not really assignin a new Tag for each new imageView,any other answer would be appreciated.

Comment: `I'm not really assignin a new Tag for each new imageView,` You are setting the tag of every image view with a (different) value. I dont know what you mean.

Comment: My code was written for adding multiple imageViews at once. Let say for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)  and it works fine when getting the tags,my real problem is how to add only one imageView at time and assign different tag so I can add different code inside each new created imageView onclicklistener

Comment: `and assign different tag ` You give the tag of every view a different value. Is that what you mean?

Comment: `So far I have implemented a button that on every click inflates a new imageView` Ahhh. my god.. i read that now.. So for every image view setTag(i) is equal to setTag(0) as i ==0; No wonder getTag() delivers 0. Just add three imageviews at every click and see that it works. I never saw that `i < 1; ` before... Why does one use a loop for one ...

Comment: `public void addImage(View view){` Change to public void addImageViews(View view){ static int tag = -1;  then your for loop and the rest.. And at the point of setTag change that to setTag(++tag);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that the loop wasn't needed, instead I used:

```
int num = linearLayout.getChildCount();
            imageView.setTag(num++);
```

Comment: `finally realized` You were told that and also the cause of your problem. Strange that you end your performance here in this way.